# Where do these styles come from in reactjs examples on codepen?

Tags: css, reactjs, codepen

[Composition-vs-inheritance React](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html)

[Documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/blob/master/content/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.md)

```
function FancyBorder(props) {
  return (
    <div className={'FancyBorder FancyBorder-' + props.color}>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
}

function WelcomeDialog() {
  return (
    <FancyBorder color="blue">
      <h1 className="Dialog-title">
        Welcome
      </h1>
      <p className="Dialog-message">
        Thank you for visiting our spacecraft!
      </p>
    </FancyBorder>
  );
}
```

https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/ozqNOV?editors=0010

Comment: which styles do you mean?

Comment: Have you opened the CSS tab on CodePen? All of the styling that's being applied to the HTML is in there.

Comment: Could you please elaborate the question here.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're viewing a pen on CodePen, the styling will most likely be applied by the code in the **CSS** section. It's possible that there is inline CSS in the HTML, and it's also possible JavaScript is manipulating the styling inline, but in all three instances you'll be dealing with [CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/) code.

The [example](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/ozqNOV) you posted is doing all of the styling in the **CSS** tab. The **HTML** tab only contains a container for the React elements to render to.

We'll use your `FancyBorder` function as an example.

```
function FancyBorder(props) {
  return (
    <div className={'FancyBorder FancyBorder-' + props.color}>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

You're constructing a `<div>` with the class name of `'FancyBorder-' + props.color`, where `props.color` is a variable that will be used later on.

Continuing with your example, you use the following code to create a welcome dialog:

```
function WelcomeDialog() {
  return (
    <FancyBorder color="blue">
      <h1>
        Welcome
      </h1>
    </FancyBorder>
  );
}
```

In this code, you're calling the `FancyBorder` function and passing through `color="blue"` which is referenced in the original function as `props.color`. It now runs `'FancyBorder-' + props.color` to generate a class named: `FancyBorder-blue`.

Now in the **CSS** section, you'll see your `FancyBorder-blue` is already setup as a class and has styling applied to it:

```
.FancyBorder-blue {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

This specific CSS applies a blue border around the box we just created. Hopefully that clears things up.

Comment: It's a good explanation to the code but the major problem was in my unawareness and stupidity. I did not know how to open those style panes when they're minimized and could not see the styles. So I searched for 3 hours straight trying to figure out where they came from. Finally found a fork where I could see the styles, explanation below.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Those styles when opened in CodePen in edit mode are not visible when tabs are minimized. It's enough to drag them open or change the link so they are opened by default. Just a CodePen feature =)

See the difference:

https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/ozqNOV?editors=0010

https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/ozqNOV

```
.FancyBorder {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border: 10px solid;
}

.FancyBorder-blue {
  border-color: blue;
}

.Dialog-title {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.Dialog-message {
  font-size: larger;
}
```

Comment: You can also just grab the **CSS** tab and drag it open, no need to change the link.